# Why doesn't my StackExchange flair show any of my associated accounts?

Tags: support, status-completed, flair, association

My StackExchange flair shows only my Area 51 rep
[image]

Even though I have multiple associated accounts with more than 200 rep:
[image]

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to generate the flair?

Comment: @Bill: I've edited it into the question.

Comment: That's weird, mine seems to work as expected.  I know the images are cached... how long ago did you start using the SE flair?

Comment: @Bill: It's been that way on Area 51 for a long time, just never got around to asking about it. I just recently got the 2nd silver badge on Area 51 and it did update to include that.

Answer (score 2):

As it says on the flair page:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flair

> (please note that only sites where you have more than 200 reputation will appear.)

Comment: Um, I count 4 sites with more than 200 rep.

Comment: @benv ah, true, I missed that -- and forwarded this on to the SE team

Comment: @Jeff, this was posted awhile ago. I am having this problem as of 2010-11-09

Comment: @dustin you *just* passed the threshold on SF, so you have to wait at least 24 hours..

Comment: @Jeff - Hi, I have a similar problem with Super User account not being a part of flair. I passed 200 mark quite a few days ago and the flair was updated several times in the meantime.

Comment: @Jeff, I also passed 200 at least 2 weeks ago. On StackExchange I see the icons, just not on the individual sites.

Comment: This is now working.

Comment: @Dustin Sorry about that. We had a bug affecting the 217 people who crossed the 200-rep threshold around Oct 24, but it's fixed now.

Comment: @Emmett, thanks! Not many sites have this kind of individual attention and follow up. You guys kick a$$!