# Do bounty points affect the limit for the StackExchange flair?

Tags: support, reputation, bounties, flair, combined-flair

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How many icons can I have on my flair?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120924/how-many-icons-can-i-have-on-my-flair)

The StackExchange flair shows accounts with a reputation more then 200.

Some time ago I reached this value for [travel.stackexchange.com](http://travel.stackexchange.com):

[image: Travel-Flair].

But the site doesn't appear in my combined flair:

[image: Combined flair]

I reached the 200 with a bounty (not really well-earned, there were just no other answers).

Is there a special calculation of reputation for the flair, e.g. without bounty reputation or without association bonus? Or is there another reason, why Travel doesn't appear in my flair?

Related question:

- [Why doesn't my StackExchange flair show any of my associated accounts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68634/why-doesnt-my-stackexchange-flair-show-any-of-my-associated-accounts)

Comment: I don't know for sure, but it seems like you might have run out of room in image.  My flair is limited 7 accounts as well and I have 14 accounts with 200+ reputation.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120924/how-many-icons-can-i-have-on-my-flair

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why it isn't appearing on your global flair is that the limit to the number of icons on it is 7. ([How many icons can I have on my flair?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120924/155190)) and it is rated by highest amount of rep you have on each site. Looking at your profile Travel looks like the eighth site.

Comment: Make sense - Thank you for the answer.